# How to convert Phonegap application into iphone Application?

Tags: iphone

I'm in problem that I need to implement my phonegap demo project into full version project. But the project will be in iphone and ipad only. I'm using xcode for doing the project but I can not control on dataflow of demo project from xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Have you created the folder reference to the www folder in Xcode as described in [the PhoneGap Getting Started with PhoneGap iOS using Xcode 4](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/39991939/Getting%20Started%20with%20PhoneGap%20iOS%20using%20Xcode%204)?

Most people i know using PhoneGap use Xcode only for compiling the project and edit the contents of the www folder with the editor of their choice, maybe this is an option for you.

Comment: hay Marko I want to go for hencewith using .xib. But I can not call my .xib file from phone gap application. Please help me>